# Kafka consumer does not print anything

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am following this tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/kafka-docker-python-408baf0e1088 in order to run a producer-consumer example using Kafka, Docker and Python. My problem is that my terminal prints the iterations of the producer, while it does not print the iterations of consumer.
I am running this example in local, so:

1. in one terminal tab I have done: `docker-compose -f docker-compose-expose.yml up` where my docker-compose-expose.yml is this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6
    ports:
     - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
     - "9092:9092"
    expose:
     - "9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "topic_test:1:1"
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I see the logs from kafka and zookeeper, so I assume that it is working.
2. In another tab I run `python producer.py` where my producer.py is this:

```
from time import sleep
from json import dumps
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
    value_serializer=lambda x: dumps(x).encode('utf-8')
)
for j in range(9999):
    print("Iteration", j)
    data = {'counter': j}
    producer.send('topic_test', value=data)
    sleep(0.5)
```

It prints the iteration, so I think it is working.
3. Finally, in another tab I run `python consumer.py` where my consumer.py is:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from json import loads
from time import sleep
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'topic_test',
    bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    enable_auto_commit=True,
    group_id='my-group-id',
    value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8'))
)
for event in consumer:
    event_data = event.value
    # Do whatever you want
    print(event_data)
    sleep(2)
```

So, here is the problem. According to the tutorial, it should print something like this:

```
{'counter': 0}
{'counter': 1}
{'counter': 2}
{'counter': 3}
{'counter': 4}
{'counter': 5}
{'counter': 6}
[...]
```

However, my terminal does not print anything.
Moreover, If I solve this problem I want to run the producer on one machine and the consumer on another machine. I need to change only `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092` in the docker-compose-expose.yml writing the IP address of the producer in place of localhost, right?

UPDATE: I tried on another machine, and these steps are now working. Maybe during my experiments I changed something about kafka or docker, so for this reason it is not working. however I do not know why

Comment: If you change the group id, what happens? If you describe the consumer group, what do you see?

Comment: I tried to comment the line with the group_id, however, again, it does not print anything

Comment: How do you know the producer is actually working? Did you exec into the container and use `kafka-console-consumer`?

Comment: The producer is printing "Iteration: 1, Iteration: 2, ...". If I change `bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092']` writing something like `bootstrap_servers=['node2:9092']` I got an error that says there is no broker. So I think that until now this configuration is working

Comment: Your configs are not the problem. I don't think your producer is being flushed after the loop. Like I said, enter into your Kafka docker container and try to run a consumer from there, separate from your own code

Comment: `kafka-console-consumer` leads to 
`kafka-console-consumer: command not found`

Comment: Did you not `docker-compose exec kafka` first?

Comment: No i don't. I am executing just the commands that I wrote in the post. Exactly as in the tutorial

Comment: Like I said, `exec` into the Kafka broker. Then run a consumer inside of that container to verify the producer actually worked. And/Or you can add `producer.flush()` after your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I had understood that the problem was in some images/processes that were in execution. With `docker-compose stop` and `docker-compose rm -f` I solved.